# Where can I find Hazelcast's "services configuration element"?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hazelcast

According to Hazelcast's doc, in order to create a custom service class you have to enable it within the "services configuration element"
as can be read here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-the-service-class

I have downloaded the hazelcast-3.9.3.jar and defined it as an external library in my newly created IntelliJ project. Where can I find this "element" or where do I have to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TMII, you need to define it in your config after creating the implementation. Please check this section: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#user-defined-services

Comment: The link is not quite correct, it should be http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.0/manual/html/ch13.html
I am going to mark this answer as the correct one, either way.

Comment: @TMII, the one that you're referring is the doc for version 2.0, what I shared is for the latest version.